# Drawing a CAShapeLayer using autolayout

Tags: swift, autolayout, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw and animate a circular button using CAShapeLayer but just the drawing gives me a lot of headache - I can't seem to figure out how to pass data into my class.

This is my setup: 
- a class of type UIView which will draw the CAShapeLayer
- the view is rendered in my view controller and built using auto layout constraints

I have tried using layoutIfNeeded but seem to be passing the data too late for the view to be drawn. I have also tried redrawing the view in vieWillLayoutSubviews() but nothing. Example code below. What am I doing wrong?

Am I passing the data too early/too late?
Am I drawing the bezierPath too late?

I'd highly appreciate pointers.

And maybe a second follow up question: is there a simpler way to draw a circular path that is bound to it's views size?

In my View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let buttonView: CircleButton = {
        let view = CircleButton()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(buttonView)
        buttonView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true
        buttonView.layoutIfNeeded()
        buttonView.arcCenter = buttonView.center
        buttonView.radius = buttonView.frame.width/2
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(buttonView.arcCenter)
        print(buttonView.radius)
    }
}
```

And the class for the buttonView:

```
class CircleButton: UIView {

    //Casting outer circular layers
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var arcCenter = CGPoint()
    var radius = CGFloat()


    //UIView Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    //UIView post init
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        print("StudyButtonView arcCenter \(arcCenter)")
        print("StudyButtonView radius \(radius)")

        layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        let outerCircularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = outerCircularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 5
        trackLayer.strokeStart = 0
        trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi/2, 0, 0, 1)
    }


    //Required for subclass
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There really isn't any correlation between auto-layout and the proper implementation of your `CircleButton` class. Your `CircleButton` class doesn't know or care whether it's being configured via auto-layout or whether it has some fixed size.

Your auto-layout code looks OK (other than points 5 and 6 below). Most of the issues in your code snippet rest in your `CircleButton` class. A couple of observations:

1. If you're going to rotate the shape layer, you have to set its `frame`, too, otherwise the size is `.zero` and it's going to end up rotating it about the `origin` of the view (and rotate outside of the `bounds` of the view, especially problematic if you're clipping subviews). Make sure to set the `frame` of the `CAShapeLayer` to be the `bounds` of the view before trying to rotate it. Frankly, I'd remove the `transform`, but given that you're playing around with `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd`, I'm guessing you may want to change these values later and have it start at 12 o'clock, in which case the transform makes sense.

   Bottom line, if rotating, set the `frame` first. If not, setting the layer's `frame` is optional.
2. If you're going to change the properties of the view in order to update the shape layer, you'll want to make sure that the `didSet` observers do the appropriate updating of the shape layer (or call `setNeedsLayout`). You don't want your view controller from having to mess around with the internals of the shape layer, but you also want to make sure that these changes do get reflected in the shape layer.
3. It's a minor observation, but I'd suggest adding the shape layer during `init` and only configuring and adding it to the view hierarchy once. This is more efficient. So, have the various `init` methods call your own `configure` method. Then, do size-related stuff (like updating the path) in `layoutSubviews`. Finally, have properties observers that update the shape layer directly. This division of labor is more efficient.
4. If you want, you can make this `@IBDesignable` and put it in its own target in your project. Then you can add it right in IB and see what it will look like. You can also make all the various properties `@IBInspectable`, and you'll be able to set them right in IB, too. You then don't have to do anything in the code of your view controller if you don't want to. (But if you want to, feel free.)
5. A minor issue, but when you add your view programmatically, you don't need to call `buttonView.layoutIfNeeded()`. You only need to do that if you're animating constraints, which you're not doing here. Once you add the constraints (and fix the above issues), the button will be laid out correctly, with no explicit `layoutIfNeeded` required.
6. Your view controller has a line of code that says:

   ```
   buttonView.arcCenter = buttonView.center
   ```

   That is conflating `arcCenter` (which is a coordinate within the `buttonView`'s coordinate space) and `buttonView.center` (which is the coordinate for the button's center *within* the view controller's root view's coordinate space). One has nothing to do with the other. Personally, I'd get rid of this manual setting of `arcCenter`, and instead have `layoutSubviews` in `ButtonView` take care of this dynamically, using `bounds.midX` and `bounds.midY`.

Pulling that all together, you get something like:

```
@IBDesignable
class CircleButton: UIView {

    private let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    @IBInspectable var lineWidth:   CGFloat = 5          { didSet { updatePath() } }
    @IBInspectable var fillColor:   UIColor = .clear     { didSet { trackLayer.fillColor   = fillColor.cgColor } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .lightGray { didSet { trackLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor  } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeStart: CGFloat = 0          { didSet { trackLayer.strokeStart = strokeStart } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeEnd:   CGFloat = 1          { didSet { trackLayer.strokeEnd   = strokeEnd } }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        trackLayer.fillColor   = fillColor.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeStart = strokeStart
        trackLayer.strokeEnd   = strokeEnd

        layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updatePath()
    }

    private func updatePath() {
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = (min(bounds.width, bounds.height) - lineWidth) / 2
        trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        trackLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

        // There's no need to rotate it if you're drawing a complete circle.
        // But if you're going to transform, set the `frame`, too.

        trackLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        trackLayer.frame = bounds
        trackLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Or you can tweak the settings right in IB, and you'll see it take effect:

[image]

And having made sure that all of the `didSet` observers for the properties of `ButtonView` either update the path or directly update some shape layer, the view controller can now update these properties and they'll automatically be rendered in the `ButtonView`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve and was lacking the right way to do it. I just ran your code (while removing the IB parts since I'm doing everything programmatically) and it works flawlessly!  bounds.midX was one of the things I was not aware I was able to get - super helpful! Two follow up questions: 1) why did you call configure() a second time during required init? 2) I'm not 100% sure I understand the didSet observer - what exactly does that do? And you mentioned an alternative would be to ask for layoutifNeeded - how would you do that? Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Oh and if it's of interest: the reason I am rotating the circular path is so that I can animate it starting at 12 o'clock instead of the default 3 o'clock position.

Comment: @moopoints - "why did you call configure() a second time during required init?" ... I'm not calling it a second time. The `init(coder:)` is called when views are created via storyboards or state restoration. The `init(frame:)` is called when you programmatically create it (or during live view in IB). They're two completely separate ways of views being created and we want this to work regardless of which one you happen to do.

Comment: @moopoints - "I'm not 100% sure I understand the didSet observer - what exactly does that do?" ... See [The Swift Programming Language: Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262). Bottom line, it's a bit of code whenever you change (but not when you first initialize) a property. You're "observing" when the property is changed by the view controller or what have you.

Comment: @moopoints - "And you mentioned an alternative would be to ask for `layoutIfNeeded` - how would you do that?" ... I'm not sure what you're referring to. The only time I use `layoutIfNeeded` is when animating a view that is defined by constraints. But you're not doing that here, so we don't need it. The only thing I was talking about was optionally calling `setNeedsLayout` in the `didSet` observer. E.g. in my `lineWidth` observer I could have called `setNeedsLayout`, which will result in `layoutSubviews` being called. In this case, calling `updatePath` was cleaner, but it's an alternative.

Comment: Excuse the late reply, Rob. Thanks again for the clarifications, super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue that I see in your code is that you are adding the layer inside `-layoutSubviews`, this method is called multiple times during a view lifecycle.
If you don't want to make the view hosted layer a `CAShapeLayer` by using the `layerClass` property, you need to override the 2 init methods (frame and coder) and call a commonInit where you instantiate and add your CAShape layer as a sublayer.
In `-layoutSubviews` just set the frame property of it and the path according to the new view size.

Comment: It’s technically not a problem to re-add the layer in `layoutSubviews`, but it is negligibly inefficient and suggests a misunderstanding of the process. So I agree with your suggestion, but it is not the root of the OP’s problem.

Comment: Thanks, Andrea! I'm not sure I fully understand your proposal. What exactly would you handle in the VC vs the class?